# Angular-ui datepicker day-format not working

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

```
config(function (datepickerConfig, datepickerPopupConfig)
{
    datepickerConfig.showWeeks = false;
    datepickerPopupConfig.toggleWeeksText = null;
    datepickerPopupConfig.dayFormat = 'd';
});
```

does not work to format the datepicker day without the padded 0 - other config options are setting correctly, but my days still have a leading zero, which is messy.

Are there other means of formatting the date?

Answer (score 0):

You need to trim the returned JavaScript date object:

```
day = day.replace(/\b0(?=\d)/g, '')
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the same thing you were asking, but I ran into an issue where specifying those options worked fine for the text-input, but I wanted to remove the leading zeros from the day in the datepicker-popup menu. The popup doesn't honor the date format, so what I ended up doing was overwriting the template for the datepicker in the template cache. Specifically, I overwrote

"template/datepicker/day.html"

And I just copied and pasted the old template, and in that html string look for `{{dt.label}}`. This is the field that is getting set with a leading 0, so to remove it I simply piped it through angular's number filter- `{{dt.label | number}}`. Works like a charm.

You can either modify the existing ui-bootstrap-tpls.js file in your project, or overwrite that template somewhere else. I opted for the latter since we automatically update our bootstrap files.

The only worry is now you have to keep an eye on bootstrap updates, since a change to the datepicker might affect you (although I think this is minimal and also it should be easily testable since you're only changing the template cache and not any datepicker code).